# Would a Colombian citizen with Canadian residency need a transit visa for the UK?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm traveling from Toronto to Madrid with one stop in London. My passport is Colombian but I'm a permanent resident in Canada.

So my question is do I need a visa or transit permit for the UK?

My itinerary is Toronto to London via Air Canada arriving London at 8:30am, and next flight same day at 10:30am London to Madrid via British Airways.

Comment: Will your bags be checked through? Or will you have to exit airside to re-check them?

Comment: I will switch from air Canada to British airways in London so I don't know if I have to exit is just 2 hours between fligths

Comment: You'll have to change terminals at the very least. Is it booked as one ticket or two? If two, you'll need to collect your bags and re-check

Answer (score 3):

YES, you generally need a visa to transit the UK

You told us that 
you are a national of Colombia.
you are coming to UK to Transit.
you are normally and legally living in Canada.

What do you need to do?

If you are coming to the UK briefly as part of your journey to another country, you will generally need to obtain a UK visa before you travel.
 If you will arrive on a flight, remain in the arrival lounge of the airport without passing through immigration control, and then depart on another flight from the same airport, you should apply for a direct airside transit visa.

http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/do-you-need-a-visa/